# how to show badge counts on launcher icon in my android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, badge, application-icon

I have tried below intent method but it does not work,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra("badge_count", 3);
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", MainActivity.class.getName());
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: use this cool [library](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

Comment: Isn't BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE Samsung specific?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing. But you can refer to third party libraries but it supports only few devices.
You can check the below library :
https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

Comment: this library does not show badger on nexus devices(manufactured by LG )